# Wired and Wireless Network Issues with PPPoE

Tags: 10.10, wireless

I have got this issue with Ubuntu 10.10. I have been with Ubuntu 8.04 and then decided to try out Ubuntu 10.10 .

I booted with a LiveCD and was able to configure the wireless network painlessly using the livecd. So happily I installed Ubuntu 10.10. As soon as Ubuntu came up it detected the wireless network and I was able to assign a static IP to eth1 (i dont use DHCP option on my ADSL router) and enter a wap key and use `pppoeconf` to configure the dialer. The net was on and I was able to surf the net. All hunky dory so far.
However on the next boot the fun started. It did not detect the wireless network. I could not see the network manager icon in the systray. I used ifconfig and saw that the entry for eth1 was missing. I used `ifup eth1` and it said that eth1 was already up .

Then I installed wifi-radar. Wifi-Radar detected the wireless network. I configured wifi-radar for the detected wireless network , set the wap driver as wext and used the manual IP settings. However on clicking connect wifi-radar started looking for a DHCP IP , needless to say it failed. For the love of god I cannot understand why wifi-radar is using DHCP when I have specified manual settings .

Next I decided to use the wired network to surf the net looking for a solution . So I plugged in the network cable from my modem , it detected the plugged in connection , I configured eth0 , used pppoeconf and connected to the net. Then I foolishly decided to reboot my PC. And wonders of wonders , the same problem appeared. I cannot see eth0 in my ifconfig anymore. I used pon to start the dsl-provider connection and it said something about network error or something . Now my ifconfig shows only lo , both eth0 and eth1 have disappeared. Can anybody help me on this?

Is it a problem with ipv6 , if so how do you disable ipv6 on Ubuntu 10.10 ? OR is this is a known issue with Ubuntu 10.10?

P.S.

1. I tried Linux mint 10 and had the same issue. On rebooting wireless network was not getting detected .
2. I have made myself the administrator so that there is no issue of rights or anything.

Comment: what's with the downvote favorite remark?  up/down votes aren't supposed to be about if you are "happy" about an issue, but if a question is constructive.  this appears to be a legitimate concern...

Comment: If you don't have anything against NetworkManager, you may try and see if things work with that. Check these two questions I posted a while ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9958/dsl-connection-not-working-in-10-04 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/cant-access-select-https-sites-on-linux-over-pppoe

Comment: @aking1012 .. i have no clue about the downvote upvote .. i have not touched anything there

Comment: @Mussnoon .... issue solved .. Used WiCD instead of networkmanager and it sorted out things ... seems like NetworkManager has some issues in 10.10

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Wired and Wireless Network Issues with PPPoE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21929/wired-and-wireless-network-issues-with-pppoe)

Answer (score 1):

In order for Network Manager to manage your wireless connection, your wireless interface must NOT be listed in /etc/network/interfaces. But pppoeconf adds it. So what you need to do is remove it.

Edit /etc/network/interfaces by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and delete the following lines:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

Restart, and you should be good to go.

Comment: . yup ... will try this one out .. though i dont get the point of NetworkManager going for a toss when your wireless interfaces are listed in the interfaces file .. i remember my interfaces file containing a entry for eth1(wireless) and network manager working OK in ubuntu 8.04...

Answer (score 1):

I happens to me every time I configure pppoe after a fresh install. After the reboot the network connections becomes unmanageable. You need to do the following:
open terminal and type:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

you will find your connection there and changed `managed=false` to `managed=true` and then restart you system. You will be able to get your network up and running again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've read the Ubuntu documentation on Wireless troubleshooting, which is available at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/

I've recently had a relative with a similar issue on his laptop. It turned out that the wireless card was disabled, and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> had to be pressed to turn it on (it may differ on your computer, e.g. a switch in front of the laptop). The command `rfkill list` should show "no" twice on Soft/ Hard blocked for "Wireless LAN".

Comment: the issue was with networkmanager ... installed wicd and its all ok now ...

Answer (score 0):

According to the questioner, using [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/) solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Comment: I'm writing this as an answer (1) to clear the unanswered queue (2) the questioner has neglected to do so for eight months.