# DSL connection keeps disconnecting

Tags: network-manager, dsl, internet-connection

I just did a fresh install of 11.10. But can't connect to the internet with the same set-up I used in 11.04. I used a DSL connection there, with only setting the username and password, it worked fine. But now, each time I make an attempt to connect, it shows "connection established" pop-up but in half a second, it again disconnects. I searched the web and found a work-around which says to set IPv6 to ignored and `killall dnsmasq` but nothing worked.

Perhaps this trick is not for me, as I am new, did not realize. However I just realized that more people are also having the issue. Now, what do I need to do to get access to internet? In 11.04 where i could connect, I was using gnome desktop. Now its Unity 3D.

I don't know what a router is. My pc is connected from the back panel of the CPU casing trough a rectangular port which glows when power is on. Then this line is connected to a black box in my house. This box says it's a "5-Port 10/100Mbps Nway Switch." From this box, two more windows pc are connected and the are fine. And another line came from outside and is connected to this box. In my wire, I checked connecting a windows pc and it worked. This black rectangular box requires AC power.

Comment: Boot using the live cd 11.10. See if the connection works there.

Comment: dsl router plz ?

Comment: @medigeek, no. It's not working with the live cd.

Comment: @One Zero, I don't know what a router is. My pc is connected from the back panel of the CPU casing trough a rectangular port which glows when power is on. Then this line is connected to a black box in my house. This box says it's a "5-Port 10/100Mbps Nway Switch." From this box, two more windows pc are connected and the are fine. And another line came from outside and is connected to this box. In my wire, I checked connecting a windows pc and it worked. This black rectangular box requires AC power.

Answer (score 1):

Since this happens in a live cd I'd suggest the following:

1. Check that you have installed any drivers that are **recommended**. Find and run "Additional drivers" program in unity.
   Restart to enable the drivers.
2. If you see that the problem persists, connect through ethernet, uninstall network-manager and install wicd-gtk (an alternative network manager):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
   sudo apt-get purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
   ```

   and restart the computer.
3. Try booting using a live cd of ubuntu 11.04 this time, see if it still allows you to connect.
4. If the above solutions still don't work, then maybe you have made some changes to the router configuration? If you know how to reset the configuration and re-enter it correctly, that would be advisable (You can always contact your DSL support service and ask for instructions). Also, set your wireless encryption to WPA/WPA2 (and not open nor WEP if that is the case). Finally, if you use the default router password, I suggest that you change it for security reasons.
5. Check out this question, maybe it's a similar problem: [DSL PPPoE connection not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9958/dsl-pppoe-connection-not-working)